# Influxdb query renaming entityid in Chronograf

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to graph CPU temps in Chronograf from a different server on the network via the IPMI input in Telegraf.

It works fine doing the following query:

```
SELECT "value" FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."ipmi_sensor" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND ("entity_id"='3.2' OR "entity_id"='3.1') GROUP BY "entity_id"
```

However, in the graph the elements are named "entity_id=3.1" and "entity_id=3.2"

How can I rename those elements on the graph? I've tried this, but I'm not coming up with the right stuff:

```
SELECT "entity_id"='3.1' AS "CPU 1" AND "entity_id"='3.2' AS "CPU 2" FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."ipmi_sensor" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: GROUP BY "entity_id"
```

I'm sure this is a simple syntax fix, but I'm just learning here and I'm stumped.